# WCF calling WSE 2.0 WS-Security service with inline security tokens in the response - "Cannot find a token authenticator"

Tags: wcf, web-services, ws-security, wse

I have a web service in .NET 1.1 and WSE 2.0 that uses WS-Security with x509 certificates for both signature and encryption.  I'm trying to configure a WCF client to connect with this service, and it's proving more challenging than I had expected.

I've gotten past most of my versioning issues by using a custom binding, but I'm stuck on one last point.  The web service includes two BinarySecurityToken elements in the response SOAP envelope -- one for the encrypting certificate, one for the signing certificate.

The problem seems to be that WCF is choking on the second token.  This is the error message:

"Cannot find a token authenticator for the 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.X509SecurityToken' token type. Tokens of that type cannot be accepted according to current security settings."

I found [this conversation on MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/520a2f77-bf7f-4662-9647-6e5237da8ab5) which describes the exact problem I'm having; but unfortunately, it doesn't provide a good resolution.  Creating a message encoder to hack the envelope into something WCF can handle seems wrong to me.  WSE 2.0 could handle inline security tokens fine -- there must be a way to force WCF to do the same.

While I do have the complete source for the original WSE 2.0 service, changing the way it handles security isn't an option at this point.

Here's the security binding element I'm currently using:

```
Dim lSBE As New System.ServiceModel.Channels.AsymmetricSecurityBindingElement()

Dim lInitiatorTokenParameters As New System.ServiceModel.Security.Tokens.X509SecurityTokenParameters
lInitiatorTokenParameters.InclusionMode = System.ServiceModel.Security.Tokens.SecurityTokenInclusionMode.AlwaysToRecipient
lInitiatorTokenParameters.X509ReferenceStyle = System.ServiceModel.Security.Tokens.X509KeyIdentifierClauseType.RawDataKeyIdentifier
lInitiatorTokenParameters.RequireDerivedKeys = False
lSBE.InitiatorTokenParameters = lInitiatorTokenParameters

Dim lRecipientTokenParameters As New System.ServiceModel.Security.Tokens.X509SecurityTokenParameters
lRecipientTokenParameters.InclusionMode = System.ServiceModel.Security.Tokens.SecurityTokenInclusionMode.AlwaysToRecipient
lRecipientTokenParameters.X509ReferenceStyle = System.ServiceModel.Security.Tokens.X509KeyIdentifierClauseType.RawDataKeyIdentifier
lRecipientTokenParameters.RequireDerivedKeys = False
lSBE.RecipientTokenParameters = lRecipientTokenParameters

lSBE.MessageSecurityVersion = MessageSecurityVersion.WSSecurity10WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10
lSBE.DefaultAlgorithmSuite = System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityAlgorithmSuite.Basic128Rsa15
lSBE.SetKeyDerivation(False)
lSBE.IncludeTimestamp = True
lSBE.AllowSerializedSigningTokenOnReply = True
lSBE.MessageProtectionOrder = System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageProtectionOrder.SignBeforeEncrypt
```

Comment: You _do_ know WSE is obsolete, don't you?

Comment: Do WSE 2.0 and WCF use the same version of WS-Security?

Comment: That's why I'm working on the upgrade path to WCF.  Unfortunately I can't just throw away the existing WSE services -- they have hundreds of existing clients.  My problem is making WCF interoperate with the existing services.

Comment: As for the security version, yes, WCF can be made to use the same version of WS-Security that WSE 2.0 did. I had to using a custom binding to ensure that all the versions matched up. I don't think the problem is versioning.  I added the security binding element code block so you can see how the security is set up on the WCF client side.  It's configured to produce the same SOAP envelope as the WSE 2.0 clients.  It succeeds at that, but can't process the BinarySecurityToken in the response for the encrypting certificate.

Comment: Please update your question with the changes you made to force WCF to use the old version of WS-Security. You might also try (as a diagnostic tool) to get a WSE 3.0 client to work with the WSE 2.0 service.

Comment: The biggest change is setting up the custom binding -- the key to it is directly configuring the AsymmetricSecurityBindingElement as opposed to using one of the preconfigured ones.  You can see I'm manually setting the MessageVersion and DefaultAlgorithmSuite as well as a number of other properties.

Comment: I should also mention that it's the token for the encrypting certificate that it can't handle...